# Hacking meta-programming via code generation in Visual Studio and C#/VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to hack together a mechanism to generate code so that I can do certain things dynamically, while preserving the benefit of strong typing.

Here's an example of the kind of thing I want to do. I've got an object like this:

```
Class Fruits
    Public Property Apple As System.Int32
    Public Property Orange As System.Int32
    Public Property Kiwi As System.Int32
    ...quite a few others
    Public Property Banana As System.Int32
    Public Property Watermelon As System.Int32
    Public Property Durian As System.Int32
End Class
```

and I have some code that does this:

```
Dim dict = myEntity.ToDictionary()
Dim myFruits = {"Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"} 

For Each fruit in myFruits
   Dim fruitValue = dict(fruit)
   doSomething(fruitValue)
Next
```

In other words, I've got a strongly typed class and I want to access properties on it, but those properties are strings determined in code.

The problem I want to avoid is that my Fruits class could change--for instance, the `Apple` property is removed. This could be because it's created via code generation or because I'm refactoring. *So then the code in the loop is broken, but the compiler has no way to warn me about this*.

---

So far, the above code is equivalent to this:

```
   fruitValue = item.Apple
   doSomething(fruitValue)

   fruitValue = item.Banana
   doSomething(fruitValue)

   fruitValue = item.Cherry
   doSomething(fruitValue)
```

If I had this code and I removed `Apple`, I'd get a compile error and all would be well.

But in reality, my list of fruits might have many more items and/or be  determined by some complex design time rule, and so writing them all out would be quite tedious and annoying to maintain.

---

**What I want is a way to write code that is pre-processed by Visual Studio at design time to generate inline, type safe code.**

I'm imagining a system and syntax where I could specify a template, the input to that template, and some sort of AddIn that would scan the code file and do the needed code generation in a partial class file. Then I could write my concise and dynamic code, but have it be expanded to explicit property accesses that would cause a compiler error if the underlying object changed.

So the question is: **how could this be implemented?**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @KeithPayne: I updated my question to be phrased as such.

Comment: I know nothing about it, but I think "Roslyn" might be what you are looking for: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Roslyn%20Overview

Comment: Can you explain what is "connection" between properties of `Fruits` and list of fruits `myFruits`? Does `myFruits` contains all possible properties or it contains only some of the properties? Are those list of properties shared between different classes or you have own list for every class? Are those properties hardcoded or they retrieved dynamically from somewhere in runtime?

Comment: You should use metaprogramming language like Nemerle.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: I'm open to it, but this needs to be part of a very large existing VB.NET solution.

Comment: Your question seems more like "XY" problem or you just take bad example for your question. For your example using reflection(use only properties which contains in the `myFruits` list) seems good enough solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to dynamically get all properties of an object:

```
var fruits = new Fruits();
foreach (var prop in fruits.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    // Do stuff here
}
```

This way when you update the object properties the above code will still iterate through them all

See [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx) for more

Comment: The question isn't how to access a property dynamically at runtime, it's about how to generate code to do it statically at compile time, to enable the compiler to catch errors of referencing a property that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection.  I'd create an extension method to get the value for the property:

```
public static object GetPropvalue(this object InputObject, string PropertyName)
{
    Type type = InputObject.GetType();
    PropertyInfo p = type.GetProperty(PropertyName);
    if (p != null)
    {
        return p.GetValue(InputObject);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
foreach (var f in myFruits)
{
    var fruitValue = myEntity.GetPropValue(f);
    if (fruitValue != null)
    {
        doSomething(fruitValue));
    }       
}
```

Comment: The question isn't how to access a property dynamically at runtime, it's about how to generate code to do it statically at compile time, to enable the compiler to catch errors of referencing a property that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

This example will do the job in compile time for your scenario without meta-programming

```vb
Public Class Fruits
    Public Property Apple As Integer
    Public Property Orange As Integer
    Public Property Kiwi As Integer        
End Class
```

And the code which using [NameOf expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) and dummy instance of `Fruits` class.

```vb
Dim dict = myEntity.ToDictionary()

Dim dummy As New Fruits()
Dim myFruits As New List(Of String) From
{
    NameOf(dummy.Apple),
    NameOf(dummy.Orange),
    NameOf(dummy.Kiwi)
} 

For Each fruit in myFruits
    Dim fruitValue = dict(fruit)
    DoSomething(fruitValue)
Next
```

This will work in your described scenario: if `Apple` property will be removed - compiler will raise an error.

But on my opinion this workaround looks more like code smell(using of dummy instance). I am sure if you will tell more about your problem you will get more proper solutions.